# How to save API response data into hive database using student model?

Tags: database, flutter, hive, local-database

The following code is for fetching student data using get API and I am using hive package link is below:

```
<https://pub.dev/packages/hive>
static Future<void> fetchStudentData() async {
var box = await Hive.openBox('studentDetails');
        
final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        
try {
print('try block${pref.getString('token')}');
final response = await http.get(
Uri.parse('https:my api url'),
headers: {
'Authorization':
'Bearer ${pref.getString('token')}', // Replace with your actual token
},
);
        
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
print('Saved');
        
box.put('details', data);
// here i want to store to parse the data into Student model and save it in 
box.put('details',parse data)
        
print('Saved ===${box.get('details')}');
} else {
throw Exception('Failed to load student data');
}
} catch (error) {
              throw Exception('Error: $error');
}}
```

**and this is my Student Model**

```
  class Student {
  List<StudentData>? studentData;

  Student({this.studentData});

  Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['StudentData'] != null) {
      studentData = <StudentData>[];
      json['StudentData'].forEach((v) {
        studentData!.add(StudentData.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.studentData != null) {
      data['StudentData'] = this.studentData!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class StudentData {
  String? formId;
  String? campusID;
  String? name;
  String? fatherName;
  String? fatherNIC;
  String? fatherOccupation;
  String? gender;
  String? dOB;
  String? religion;
  String? photo;
  String? domicile;
  String? placeOfBirth;
  String? nationality;
  String? bFormNo;
  String? bloodGroup;
  String? anuualIncome;
  String? motherName;
  String? motherNIC;
  String? guardianName;
  String? motherOccupation;
  String? guardianNIC;
  String? guardianOccupation;
  String? nIC;
  String? formEntryDate;
  String? busID;
  String? transport;
  String? hafizQuran;
  String? hostelRequired;
  String? lefthaded;
  String? maritaStatus;
  String? disability;
  String? description;
  String? diseases;
  String? stdId;
  String? regId;
  String? admissionDate;
  String? session;
  String? leavingDate;
  String? mainSection;
  String? programName;
  String? classID;
  String? section;
  String? status;
  String? shift;
  String? scholorShip;
  String? scholorshipType;
  String? reasonForLeaving;
  String? boardRegistrationNo;
  String? type;
  String? iD;
  String? isExpelled;
  String? fatherNo;
  String? guardianNo;
  String? motherNo;
  String? homeNo;
  String? officeNo;
  String? other;
  String? sMS1;
  String? sMS2;
  String? lastClass;
  String? area;
  String? fatherEducation;
  String? motherEducation;
  String? guardianEducation;
  String? fatherDesignation;
  String? urduLevel;
  String? guardianDepartment;
  String? fatherDepartment;
  String? guardianDesignation;
  String? concessionDescription;
  String? concessionFrom;
  String? concessionTo;
  String? totalPresents;
  String? outOf;
  String? conduct;
  String? remarks;
  String? sLCNo;

  StudentData(
      {this.formId,
      this.campusID,
      this.name,
      this.fatherName,
      this.fatherNIC,
      this.fatherOccupation,
      this.gender,
      this.dOB,
      this.religion,
      this.photo,
      this.domicile,
      this.placeOfBirth,
      this.nationality,
      this.bFormNo,
      this.bloodGroup,
      this.anuualIncome,
      this.motherName,
      this.motherNIC,
      this.guardianName,
      this.motherOccupation,
      this.guardianNIC,
      this.guardianOccupation,
      this.nIC,
      this.formEntryDate,
      this.busID,
      this.transport,
      this.hafizQuran,
      this.hostelRequired,
      this.lefthaded,
      this.maritaStatus,
      this.disability,
      this.description,
      this.diseases,
      this.stdId,
      this.regId,
      this.admissionDate,
      this.session,
      this.leavingDate,
      this.mainSection,
      this.programName,
      this.classID,
      this.section,
      this.status,
      this.shift,
      this.scholorShip,
      this.scholorshipType,
      this.reasonForLeaving,
      this.boardRegistrationNo,
      this.type,
      this.iD,
      this.isExpelled,
      this.fatherNo,
      this.guardianNo,
      this.motherNo,
      this.homeNo,
      this.officeNo,
      this.other,
      this.sMS1,
      this.sMS2,
      this.lastClass,
      this.area,
      this.fatherEducation,
      this.motherEducation,
      this.guardianEducation,
      this.fatherDesignation,
      this.urduLevel,
      this.guardianDepartment,
      this.fatherDepartment,
      this.guardianDesignation,
      this.concessionDescription,
      this.concessionFrom,
      this.concessionTo,
      this.totalPresents,
      this.outOf,
      this.conduct,
      this.remarks,
      this.sLCNo});

  StudentData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    formId = json['FormId'];
    campusID = json['CampusID'];
    name = json['Name'];
    fatherName = json['FatherName'];
    fatherNIC = json['FatherNIC'];
    fatherOccupation = json['FatherOccupation'];
    gender = json['Gender'];
    dOB = json['DOB'];
    religion = json['Religion'];
    photo = json['Photo'];
    domicile = json['Domicile'];
    placeOfBirth = json['PlaceOfBirth'];
    nationality = json['Nationality'];
    bFormNo = json['B_FormNo'];
    bloodGroup = json['BloodGroup'];
    anuualIncome = json['AnuualIncome'];
    motherName = json['MotherName'];
    motherNIC = json['MotherNIC'];
    guardianName = json['GuardianName'];
    motherOccupation = json['MotherOccupation'];
    guardianNIC = json['GuardianNIC'];
    guardianOccupation = json['GuardianOccupation'];
    nIC = json['NIC'];
    formEntryDate = json['FormEntryDate'];
    busID = json['BusID'];
    transport = json['Transport'];
    hafizQuran = json['HafizQuran'];
    hostelRequired = json['HostelRequired'];
    lefthaded = json['Lefthaded'];
    maritaStatus = json['MaritaStatus'];
    disability = json['Disability'];
    description = json['Description'];
    diseases = json['Diseases'];
    stdId = json['StdId'];
    regId = json['RegId'];
    admissionDate = json['AdmissionDate'];
    session = json['Session'];
    leavingDate = json['LeavingDate'];
    mainSection = json['MainSection'];
    programName = json['ProgramName'];
    classID = json['ClassID'];
    section = json['Section'];
    status = json['Status'];
    shift = json['Shift'];
    scholorShip = json['ScholorShip'];
    scholorshipType = json['ScholorshipType'];
    reasonForLeaving = json['ReasonForLeaving'];
    boardRegistrationNo = json['BoardRegistrationNo'];
    type = json['Type'];
    iD = json['ID'];
    isExpelled = json['IsExpelled'];
    fatherNo = json['FatherNo'];
    guardianNo = json['GuardianNo'];
    motherNo = json['MotherNo'];
    homeNo = json['HomeNo'];
    officeNo = json['OfficeNo'];
    other = json['Other'];
    sMS1 = json['SMS1'];
    sMS2 = json['SMS2'];
    lastClass = json['LastClass'];
    area = json['Area'];
    fatherEducation = json['FatherEducation'];
    motherEducation = json['MotherEducation'];
    guardianEducation = json['GuardianEducation'];
    fatherDesignation = json['FatherDesignation'];
    urduLevel = json['UrduLevel'];
    guardianDepartment = json['GuardianDepartment'];
    fatherDepartment = json['FatherDepartment'];
    guardianDesignation = json['GuardianDesignation'];
    concessionDescription = json['ConcessionDescription'];
    concessionFrom = json['ConcessionFrom'];
    concessionTo = json['ConcessionTo'];
    totalPresents = json['TotalPresents'];
    outOf = json['OutOf'];
    conduct = json['Conduct'];
    remarks = json['Remarks'];
    sLCNo = json['SLCNo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['FormId'] = this.formId;
    data['CampusID'] = this.campusID;
    data['Name'] = this.name;
    data['FatherName'] = this.fatherName;
    data['FatherNIC'] = this.fatherNIC;
    data['FatherOccupation'] = this.fatherOccupation;
    data['Gender'] = this.gender;
    data['DOB'] = this.dOB;
    data['Religion'] = this.religion;
    data['Photo'] = this.photo;
    data['Domicile'] = this.domicile;
    data['PlaceOfBirth'] = this.placeOfBirth;
    data['Nationality'] = this.nationality;
    data['B_FormNo'] = this.bFormNo;
    data['BloodGroup'] = this.bloodGroup;
    data['AnuualIncome'] = this.anuualIncome;
    data['MotherName'] = this.motherName;
    data['MotherNIC'] = this.motherNIC;
    data['GuardianName'] = this.guardianName;
    data['MotherOccupation'] = this.motherOccupation;
    data['GuardianNIC'] = this.guardianNIC;
    data['GuardianOccupation'] = this.guardianOccupation;
    data['NIC'] = this.nIC;
    data['FormEntryDate'] = this.formEntryDate;
    data['BusID'] = this.busID;
    data['Transport'] = this.transport;
    data['HafizQuran'] = this.hafizQuran;
    data['HostelRequired'] = this.hostelRequired;
    data['Lefthaded'] = this.lefthaded;
    data['MaritaStatus'] = this.maritaStatus;
    data['Disability'] = this.disability;
    data['Description'] = this.description;
    data['Diseases'] = this.diseases;
    data['StdId'] = this.stdId;
    data['RegId'] = this.regId;
    data['AdmissionDate'] = this.admissionDate;
    data['Session'] = this.session;
    data['LeavingDate'] = this.leavingDate;
    data['MainSection'] = this.mainSection;
    data['ProgramName'] = this.programName;
    data['ClassID'] = this.classID;
    data['Section'] = this.section;
    data['Status'] = this.status;
    data['Shift'] = this.shift;
    data['ScholorShip'] = this.scholorShip;
    data['ScholorshipType'] = this.scholorshipType;
    data['ReasonForLeaving'] = this.reasonForLeaving;
    data['BoardRegistrationNo'] = this.boardRegistrationNo;
    data['Type'] = this.type;
    data['ID'] = this.iD;
    data['IsExpelled'] = this.isExpelled;
    data['FatherNo'] = this.fatherNo;
    data['GuardianNo'] = this.guardianNo;
    data['MotherNo'] = this.motherNo;
    data['HomeNo'] = this.homeNo;
    data['OfficeNo'] = this.officeNo;
    data['Other'] = this.other;
    data['SMS1'] = this.sMS1;
    data['SMS2'] = this.sMS2;
    data['LastClass'] = this.lastClass;
    data['Area'] = this.area;
    data['FatherEducation'] = this.fatherEducation;
    data['MotherEducation'] = this.motherEducation;
    data['GuardianEducation'] = this.guardianEducation;
    data['FatherDesignation'] = this.fatherDesignation;
    data['UrduLevel'] = this.urduLevel;
    data['GuardianDepartment'] = this.guardianDepartment;
    data['FatherDepartment'] = this.fatherDepartment;
    data['GuardianDesignation'] = this.guardianDesignation;
    data['ConcessionDescription'] = this.concessionDescription;
    data['ConcessionFrom'] = this.concessionFrom;
    data['ConcessionTo'] = this.concessionTo;
    data['TotalPresents'] = this.totalPresents;
    data['OutOf'] = this.outOf;
    data['Conduct'] = this.conduct;
    data['Remarks'] = this.remarks;
    data['SLCNo'] = this.sLCNo;
    return data;
  }
}
```

In fetching method after decode the body response how I will convert it model and then it in local database, when I am trying to parse to model it shows two options  `Student.fromJson` and `StudentData.fromJson`. Here I am confused.

Comment: If your api's response giving you a list of student details (which i think it is), than you need to use `Student`'s `fromJson` method, and if it's giving a single student's detail than use `StudentData.fromJson`